# Reducing Pg_largeobject size in AWS RDS

Tags: database, postgresql, blob, amazon-rds, largeobject

We have RDS PostgreSQL database orignally-35GB (now extended to 60 GB). All our core tables not occupying more than 20mb space but our Pg_largeobject occupies -35Gb though we are not having any blob storage.
1.Want to know what actually fills the Pg_largeobject  table.
2.Found this post but there are no solutions which really worked in RDS environment.
(https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/174663/how-to-vacuumlo-an-rds-postgresql-database)

Comment: Why don't the solutions work?

Comment: @jjanes as per the suggestion after running the script and performing  vacuum full on pg_largeobject and pg_largeobject_metadata  only size of pg_largeobject_metadata getting reduces and not pg_largeobject

Comment: On a hosted database, there is probably not much you can do, except to delete *all* large objects and wait for autovacuum truncation. You certainly are using large objects.